# Should a system be able to render things? (ECS)

Tags: c#, entity-system, component-based

I'm currently building an entity component system and I just have one question... Should a system be allowed to render things to the screen?

For example, should I make a SpriteComponent that contains a Sprite, and then create a SpriteRenderSystem that renders the sprite to the screen? Or should rendering entities be managed by something else entirely?

The reason I ask is because I've read in many forums that allowing a system to render is a bad idea. But I just don't understand why this is; If game objects in my game are represented using the ECS, how else would I go about rendering objects to the screen?

Comment: Perfect systems don't exist. Do whatever you're comfortable with. It'sll get a burden eventually.

Comment: Isn't the render system....a system? I'd imagine your system class forwards all of the rendering commands to a render system? You can probably do it directly if you don't have such a setup.

Comment: There is no such thing as _the ECS_. What is you E, what is your C and what is your S? What do they do and how are they related? There is as many definition of ECS as there are developers.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt actually no, there are only different definitions of component based architecture, but even then they're just different design patterns. ECS (Entity Component System) is a architectural pattern commonly used in game development programming; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-component-system

Comment: @Mathew There are obviously different interpretations / approaches / meanings of the ECS pattern since **your** implementation is different from **my** implementation and from the **common** implementation where an entity is nothing but an ID and a component **only** holds data and does not have any functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best approach, but it works for me:

The *ECS* is used for logical storage and operations *only* (or almost only).

The design I use is aiming to separate these two concerns as much as possible. Naturally somehow you need to be able to tell any rendering code how to render a given entity, I do that using a component on my entities that stores a graphical representation of the entity. This representation could be a simple sprite, a whole spritesheet, a bunch of triangles, and so forth.

To decide what I render, my ECS has a *Camera-System*. This system has a certain box in world-space it *sees*. Any entities that are located in that box and have a representation-component are picked up by the Camera-System, batched and queued for rendering.

The renderer runs, in my case, on another thread and picks up a snapshot of all cameras every frame - then renders it.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this. There is no definitive *"good"* or *"bad"*, just what **works**. I've always used a `SpriteComponent` and a `SpriteRenderingSystem`. It's the most simple and straight-forward way and it has worked for all of my games. If you feel like it's not the correct thing to do then change it to be whatever you want / need. Just do whatever feels right and whatever **works** and it will be fine in the end.